# Promql / prometheus query to grab the total number of data points within a range

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, victoriametrics

I want to get the number of pipelines that passed that are happening within my gitlab repo. I am trying to get the total number of data points within a 4w(1 month). I am using grafana to see the data visually. I first start getting the points individually and start counting them manually and checking them them in our repo pipeline to make sure they match which they do.

```
query=pipeline_status{branch="master", status="success", source!="schedule", passed_with_warnings="no",project_repo="nik"}
```

> Note: These query gives the 22 data points they were run and how long they ran for

[image: Grafana Points]

EDIT:

I wanted to count the number of pipeline status within that day, so I queried for with a step of 1d

```
count(pipeline_duration{branch="master", status="success", source!="schedule", passed_with_warnings="no",project_id="930"}[1d])OR vector(0)
```

This shows the correct 22 data points within that month period (3/20 - 4/20)
[image: day qyery]

Now when I add a count to my query for a 4 week step doesn't match. I should expect to see 22 data points, but graph seems off.

```
query=count(pipeline_status{branch="master", status="success", source!="schedule", passed_with_warnings="no",project_repo="nik"}[4w])OR vector(0)'
```

[image: query]

Comment: Also, it would be easier to help, if you'll add a couple examples of time series returned by your first query.

Comment: Can you see the above images @markalex

Comment: Well, it could be the rare case when screenshots were helpful)

Comment: I'm not familiar with victoriaMetrics, but it seems suspicious that your last seen value is for `13.04`, while clearly there are more values later. If you are interested in reasons, I would advise you to check results of this query in web UI of your server (assuming it is similar to UI of Prometheus) and documentation of metricsQL on `count` applied to range vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [count_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time) function in the following fashion:

```
count_over_time(pipeline_status{branch="master", status="success", source!="schedule", passed_with_warnings="no",project_repo="nik"}[4w])
```

`count_over_time(series_selector[d])` is a rollup function, which calculates the number of raw samples on the given lookbehind window d per each time series returned from the given series_selector.

Metric names are stripped from the resulting rollups. Add keep_metric_names modifier in order to keep metric names.

Comment: It didn't seem to work. Adding the `count_over_time` gave me a data that was zero

Comment: This is unexpected. Are you sure the label filters were correct? Did you use any extra filtering? Can you share the raw datapoints exported via export API (https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-export-data-in-json-line-format)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VictoriaMetrics, so proceed with caution.

If its metricQL is reverse compatible with promQL, you can use combination of [`last_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) and `count` to calculate number of separate in time values.

For your metric it would be

```
count(last_over_time(pipeline_status{branch="master", status="success", source!="schedule", passed_with_warnings="no",project_repo="nik"} [4w]))
```

Here `last_over_time` "stretches" last seen value till now, if it was seen within specified time range.